# I cant see the disk I removed from an external canon harddrive CS100

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, disk-management

I had a canon external hard drive that I could upload photos from WI-FI at home.
The power supply stopped working and I now want to get the photos off the hard drive.

I have removed the drive and connected it to my PC with a sata to USB connection.
However, the drive does not show up in "This PC", and I have looked at disk management and it is visible there but not accessible anywhere else.

Has anybody any suggestions on how to get the photos off the drive. The device management shows the drive as an SCSI device? Not sure what this indicates.
Thank toy for the help

Right click at 915.32 GB:

> [image]

Right click at `Disk 1` 931.51 GB

> [image]

Device manager:

> [image]

Disk Management Details:

> [image]

Comment: It may be the filesystems there are of types not supported by Windows. Boot Linux live CD/USB and investigate from there. Useful commands: `lsblk`, `gdisk -l /dev/sdX`, `file -s /dev/sdX1` (`sdX2`, `sdX3` etc.), where `sdX` should be replaced with the right device node. Some commands may need `sudo`. Report back ([edit] the question) and maybe we will be able to help more.

Comment: (cont'd) The device may be `sg` instead of `sd`. I don't work with SCSI, I'm not sure. Anyway `lsblk` should tell you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Disk Management utility, you should right-click the partition you want to access (probably the one of 915.32GB in your case) and choose **Change Drive Letters and Paths**. There you will be able to assign a drive letter to the partition.